# Prove that if $A$ is an infinite set and $A \sim B$, then $B$ is an infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My questions reads:

Prove that if $A$ is an infinite set and $A \sim B$, then $B$ is an infinite set.

Comment: May I ask what your definition of infinite set is?

Comment: Hint: you know $A$ has a proper subset, call it $A'$, which is in bijection with $A$. Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a bijection. Try to use it to find a proper subset $B'$ of $B$ which is in bijection with $B$.

Comment: What does $\sim$ mean?  If it means there is a bijection $f:A \leftarrow\rightarrow B$ then what does "infinite mean".  If that means there exist and injective function $g:\mathbb N \rightarrow A$ then $f\circ g:\mathbb N \rightarrow B$ is injective.  So $B$ is infinite.

Comment: Oh... I guess Wojowu's definition of infinite is actually better than mine.  By a lot.  But .... well again.... if $f: A\rightarrow B$ is a bijection is the definition of $A \sim B$ then for any $A' \subsetneq A$ then $f(A') \subsetneq f(A) = B$.  If $A$ is infinite there is a $A' \subset A$ so that $A' \sim A$ and $A' \sim f(A')\subsetneq B$ and $A'\sim A$ and $A\sim B$ and $\sim$ is transitive and symmetric so $f(A') \sim B$ so $B$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $f\colon A\to B$ to be a bijection. If $A'\subsetneq A$ and $A'\sim A$, then $B'=f[A']=\{f(a)\mid a\in A'\}$ is a subset of $B$. Now what can you say about the cardinalities of $A,A',B$ and $B'$?

Comment: What does A' mean?

Comment: @Sam In this case, it's just the name of a proper subset of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f \colon A \to B$ be a bijection. Since $A$ is infinite, there is some proper subset $C \subsetneq A$ and a bijection $g \colon C \to A$. Now let $$
D := f"C = \{ f(c) \mid c \in C\}.
$$
Note that $D \subsetneq B$ is a proper subset. Furthermore
$$
g \circ f^{-1} \colon D \to B, f(c) \mapsto g(c)
$$
is a bijection, witnessing that $B$ is infinite.